# Best way to pull rss Feed

Tags: php, xml, rss

I've got myself an rss feed, here it is:

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <rss xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/' xmlns:blogger='http://schemas.google.com/blogger/2008' xmlns:georss='http://www.georss.org/georss' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:thr='http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0' version='2.0'>
  <channel>
  <atom:id>tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-2079382764445278058</atom:id>
  <lastBuildDate>Wed, 23 Oct 2013 18:38:23 +0000</lastBuildDate>
  <title>Whaaa</title>
  <description>Blog tests....</description>
  <link>http://whateverblog.blogspot.com/</link>
  <managingEditor>noreply@blogger.com (The author)</managingEditor>
  <generator>Blogger</generator>
  <openSearch:totalResults>1</openSearch:totalResults>
  <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
  <openSearch:itemsPerPage>25</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
  <item>
  <guid isPermaLink='false'>tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-2079382764445278058.post-6231173351434517354</guid>
  <pubDate>Wed, 23 Oct 2013 13:15:00 +0000</pubDate>
  <atom:updated>2013-10-23T11:38:23.407-07:00</atom:updated>
  <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
  <description>span style="background-color: white; color: #444444; font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px;"&gt;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.&lt;/span&gt;</description>
  <link>http://myblog.blogspot.com/2013/10/lorem-ipsum.html</link>
  <author>noreply@blogger.com (The Author)</author>
  <thr:total>0</thr:total>
  </item>
 </channel>
 </rss>
```

I've got the html template for the posts, but my problem is that I don't know whats the best way to get this information, copy it & paste it on the template.html....

Do you guys have any solution for this?

Whats the easiest way to achieve this?

////For the sake of shortness, lets just say we only want :

```
Published
Title
Description
Author
```

How can I create an html document with that information.
For example:

firstpost.html (firstpost is the name of the post title..)

```
<div id="title">Here Goes Post Title </div>
<divid="date">Here Goes Post Submission Date </div>
<div id="content"> Here Goes Post Description </div>
<div id="author"> Here goes Post Author </div>
```

Comment: Perhaps variables is a new concept to you? Otherwise what you ask about sounds like a classic XSLT transformation as well.

Comment: @hakre Oh no, its just Im coming from another kingdom, I come from objective-c and Im stepping into the website,servers realm....not that different but the syntax can get me sometimes hahaha, do you happen to have any links to any forum/blog that teaches a simple xslt transformation in a simple manner?

Comment: You can take a look here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-introxslt/

Answer (score 0):

For example with a function like:

```
function getRssFeed($feedString) {  

    $content = file_get_contents($feedString);  
    $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);  

    echo "<ul>";  

    foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {  
        echo "<li><a href='{$entry->link}' title='{$entry->title}'>" . $entry->title . "</a></li>";  
    }  
    echo "</ul>";  
}
```

You parse very simple a feed with **[SimpleXmlElement](http://www.php.net/manual/ro/class.simplexmlelement.php)**

Comment: if you output HTML you need to properly encode strings you output. Here you don't. This can make especially sense with RSS contents that sometimes also ships in mixed-mode and is an interesting use-case.